# Delete A File That Contains The App Name (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, delete-file

This is the code I'm Using:

```
Dim file As String
    Dim prefetchPath As String
    Dim FileName As String = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName
    prefetchPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) & "\Prefetch"
    For Each file In IO.Directory.GetFiles(prefetchPath)
        If file.Contains(FileName) Then
            IO.File.Delete(file)
        End If
    Next
```

i don't know why it does not work if i use `FileName`. But it work if i use this code

```
If file.Contains("Example.exe") Then
            IO.File.Delete(file)
        End If
```

I want to make sure that if someone changes the name of the application the code works the same way(I already running the file as Administrator)
Help me Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `FileName` contains the string you are thinking it contains?

Comment: yes...But I don't know if I have to specify something (example "or \)

Comment: Also - please indicate the error you are receiving (if, in fact, you are experiencing an error).

Comment: it doesn't give any error

Comment: I suggest you step through your code with a local watch on the `file` variable and the `FileName` variable. Then, when you come across your executing assembly name in the loop, use the Immediate window to check `file.Contains(FileName)`. It should be clear that either a) you aren't,in fact, finding your executing assembly in your loop or b) the string comparison isn't what you are anticipating.

Comment: Ok, I Found the problem thanks. Since the file is capitalized when it searches in the file name it does not find it because it looks for it in lower case, how do I make it find `If file.Contains(Filename)` uppercase

Comment: `If file.ToLower().Contains(FileName.ToLower()) Then` or use `.ToUpper()` if that is your preference.

Comment: Thanks man, It Work but how can i stop the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that AssemblyName only returns the name without the extension, try including the .exe. Also, it is worth noting that you can use the IO.DirectoryInfo class and pass the file name in the GetFiles method to cut out your For/Each loop.

Here is a quick example:

```
Dim prefetchPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine), "Prefetch")
Dim FileName As String = My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe"

If New IO.DirectoryInfo(prefetchPath).GetFiles(FileName).Count > 0 Then
    IO.File.Delete(IO.Path.Combine(prefetchPath, FileName))
End If
```

Comment: Bro i already found the error, Since the file is capitalized when it searches in the file name it does not find it because it looks for it in lower case, how do I make it find `If file.Contains(Filename)` uppercase

Comment: Seeing as `New IO.DirectoryInfo(prefetchPath).GetFiles(FileName)` can only return one file in this case, why not just do `If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(prefetchPath, FileName)) Then` instead to save processing power?